Identify a show with a heavyset bearded detective and family members solving a mansion murder mystery
It came out on Netflix during 2005-2022. I think it was Spanish-spoken but dubbed, and not sure it lasted more than one season. The series starts with 2-3 groups of families meeting at a mansion and no one seems to like each other outside of their own group. Then someone ends up murdered and a detective gets called in.
The things I remember are:

The detective is a heavyset guy with a beard and isn't the best at doing detective work: the detective, while studying the dead body, takes out the knife, realizes everyone is watching, and shoves the knife back in as everyone gasps (this very prominent scene could be seen in the preview/commercial for the series).

The daughter of one of the families helps to solve the murder, and one of her family members who talks a lot has purple hair.

It ends on a cliffhanger where a murder is heard in a phone message.

Pretty much the whole show takes places at the mansion where the murder happened.



Already discounted:

A Deadly Invitation
Handsome


You might want to mention all the shows you've already discounted; https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1eny89o/tomttv2010searly2020s_detective_families_members/ / https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1duq0lk/tomttv_show2020s_where_the_detective_when/

Will wait since it’s a different site

@ChristopherDavison if there are more series you already discarded you should mention in your Q here - we are not going over to check it on reddit every time.

Luciano I am not asking people to check Reddit which I am not asking people to do. Only 1 or 2 answers are on it maybe so in the future if I decide to do so.

It's a TV show called
“Unsuspicious”/“Nada Suspeitos” (2022). Still on Netflix but only lasted a season. Was able to look at past watch history and found it.

The police arrive, tape off the crime scene, dust for fingerprints, and so on, while the families wait.  A Columbo-type bumbling detective bursts in, stumbles into the crime scene, and accidentally pulls out the knife! "Everyone here is a suspect," he announces, "So no one leaves until we figure out whodunit."
Per review





Please [edit] your answer to add more details on how this TV show answers the question. You can find tips on how to write a good identification answer and what details to add in our guide.

It sounds like The Chalet (original French title Le Chalet) (2017-2018), a French-Spanish crime thriller that premiered on Netflix in 2018.

The story starts with several groups of people meeting at a remote mansion in the French Alps, where tensions run high and the groups don't seem to get along well.
A murder occurs, and a detective is called in to investigate. The detective is somewhat clumsy, bearded, and somewhat inept investigator.
The daughter of one of the families (who becomes involved in solving the crime) plays a key role in the investigation.
One of the family members (Inès) has purple hair
The series ends on a cliffhanger with a murder revealed in a phone message, keeping the tension and mystery unresolved.

You can still find it On Netflix.


Does he pull the knife out of the murder victim?

@Valorum I can't find that scene, so I'm not sure. It's also not on the trailer, and there are not a lot of details about it anywhere

Thanks for suggestion but no, few simulator things.

Could this be the Adam Sandler 'comedy' Murder Mystery (2019)?
The film takes place in a mansion. After the murder, one of the characters, not a detective, but a  partygoer, asks if he should pull out the knife from the victim. The other guests say he shouldn't but he does anyway. After they yell at him, he puts the knife back into the victim.
The character is heavyset and the film does feature a detective.


Same situation of what happens of but it’s not a movie & not dubbed & as you pointed out not the Detective as to the TV show that I am trying to find is.
